# Translating this code from python to java

Tags: python, java, sha256, hmac

I am trying to translate this piece of python code to java however I have so far had no luck.

```py
hmac_key = base64.b64decode(secret)
digest = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature = base64.b64encode(digest).decode('utf-8')
```

This is my current java implementation.

```java
byte[] hmac_key = base64().decode(secret);
String hash = Hashing.hmacSha256(hmac_key).hashString(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
String updatedMsg = base64().encode(hash.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Why do these two pieces of code return different outputs?

Comment: You can add language name to code like ```java

Comment: @Leo no it doesnt give me any errors however the signature generated by python allows me to consume the API the java implementation doesn't.

Comment: You add the name only after the first three `'s like *three apostrophes* python <code> *three apostrophes* You can look at the formatting guide

Comment: which dependency are you using in java? builtin base64?

Comment: @deadshot im using guava BaseEncoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` method on generated hash instead use `asBytes()`

```
byte[] hmacKey = base64().decode(secret);
byte[] hash = Hashing.hmacSha256(hmacKey).hashString(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).asBytes();
String updatedMsg = base64().encode(hash);
```